# F# Function Statistics.EmpiricalInvCDF() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, f#, statistics

I am converting a legacy piece of code from F# to python where the Statistics.EmpiricalInvCDF() method is being used. I am having trouble replicating this in python. Here is the documentation for the F# method (https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/DescriptiveStatistics.html#Empirical-Distribution-Functions)

The usecase is as follows:

```
given list: 

[0.03230313262534688, 0.002645726276523705, 0.01159854312582566, 0.0, 0.13521878503682389, 0.04221995336868746, 0.08088206039629423, 0.057687700498838576, -0.008598786901065152, 0.042606344490953324, 0.011082772426956695, 0.07893807796386074, 0.04300878546372856, 0.05772152131808002, 0.6630361642770063, -0.6198730776408921, 0.0481094085159463, 0.1848513533230482, -0.05577620426994041, 0.1029537374891358, 
0.10357978356369431, 0.12254238149057754, 0.0911269446223479, 0.01932811172408364, 0.06932530865454888, -0.004110301433067377, 0.05802985444298547, 0.014621095574236822, -0.4615159515258704, -0.0012407645052369416, 0.03286149662750687, 0.012825027001045838, 0.051867696499045116, 0.020623116252775197, 0.02446469695619617, -0.015974966074344284, 0.03939323769642985, 0.5652557818438808, 0.02508486624629729, 
0.026311401768164447, 0.03827223792998286, 0.03867025726520796, 0.04285045108159155, 0.018009295529766094, -0.18204238698737224, 0.03890486510159634, 0.03852683399121745, 0.17287557452039864, 0.022755267696871983, -0.008620053014231119, -0.21249945562739217, 0.009220137475520283, 0.030352843001682523, 0.0, -0.05843788432673845, 0.04484955168754013, 0.006260357642714611, 0.026573389912263958, 0.040894080492335595, 0.031156642520786194, -0.0035593767458410395, 0.056502452728941756, -0.011567687131086034, 0.019824618387320487, 0.01763256480698061, 0.03770396875280739, -0.2169605977183593, -0.04877029469675406, 0.03168933055587481, 0.032420547672104144, 0.03079075024741443, 0.1653012750667534, -0.006804319891639613, 0.008984055440418937, 0.0199408085772636, 0.020428069981471644, 0.04359405356382086, 0.015103293654879058, -0.023375468526050273, -0.00933222120934053, 0.02321095571832252, 0.049559948387087396, -0.0004151086139435974, -0.15655953473681927, 0.004304419664092396, 0.006671355318000576, -0.02449338530147379, 0.04478202409774672, -0.2629400383137885, 0.1954843319620695, 0.03686504887911304, -0.2684481840299527, -0.019138442894774923, 0.00621584280949767, 0.06460718118510203, -0.20020564142388894, -0.035691664770196155, 0.2577033446666525, 0.032908740476793354, 0.06685955822175448, 0.04128016090027627, 0.03690468165039895, -0.02095094349421612, 0.018320834968663716, 0.07261850788704553, 0.0005996187229608711, -0.005294975699828886, 0.07868580727177386, -0.14683416493836995, 0.06367912640840617, 0.08829914546925684, 0.01925506982025991, -0.01845931029495414, 0.016455918131923757, -0.10730938773869152, 0.06959721883549888, -0.24295927354223984, 0.038191715674122884, 0.2489265941534765, 0.25367195299667944, -0.24074284601722426, 0.04790264523942938, -0.2898539131116597, 0.46076135068477636, 0.16892117107930602, 0.032233962259842104, 0.10991351750112961, 0.0947295624169787, -0.31877746856009903, 0.08839333002165493, 0.05967730549716063, -0.012206209535519416, 0.06258238056246512, 0.11311371649813944, -0.18662709898356242, 0.042107091229495866, 0.025462668074737474, 0.07075281119631686, -0.026548329376822558, 0.051226289479552996, -0.23413933396499512, 0.1898393060388359, 0.028314404612467214, 0.02164091611437012, 0.055312288886916146, -0.30925915849671126, 0.1197828763807938, 0.06086095889478898, 0.03277084074489599, 0.034771448102962066, -0.006071302642726877, 0.015918735667438268, 0.10892314394119058, 0.10288895121802186, -0.24608601414818557, 0.04226840237554879, 0.1279809775740312, -0.019354369564949375, 0.0]

emp_inv = Statistics.EmpiricalInvCDF(list, 0.01)
```

expected output:

```
emp_inv = -0.52626813800271377
```

Comment: I guess you need to use `mquantiles` in some way, but I'm not sure how exactly to configure it to do what you need: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles.html

Comment: looks like thats for empirical cdf, do you know how i'd be able to inverse it? further, would this just translate to linear interpolation?